# Alternative for glBindTextureUnit for OpenGL versions less than 4.5?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing a small engine in C++ and I am trying to write a batch renderer I can use glBindTextureUnit for systems with 4.5 but systems like those of Apples don't have it because they don't want to update OpenGL but you can still use 4.1. So what is the Alternative for those lower than 4.5?

Comment: "*they don't want to update OpenGL but you can still use 4.1.*" FYI: OpenGL support on MacOS is deprecated and may be removed at Apple's whims. It would be best not to try to rely on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glBindTextureUnit(unit, texture)` is almost identical to

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

The only difference is that the second version will alter the active texture global state.
When using something else than a 2D texture, the first parameter of `glBindTexture` might have to be adjusted.