# Binding 2 different texture units, but only one will get rendered in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, glfw

Having this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

uint32_t LoadTexture(const std::string& filepath) {
    int w, h, bits;

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    uint8_t *pixels = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &w, &h, &bits, 4);

    uint32_t texture_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    stbi_image_free(pixels);
    return texture_id;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513272/alternative-for-glbindtextureunit-for-opengl-versions-less-than-4-5
void Bind2DTexture(int unit, uint32_t texture) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
}


int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "test", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "failed to create GLFW window\n";
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow *_, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    });
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cerr << "failed to initialize GLAD\n";
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Shader shader("assets/GLSL/test.glsl");
    shader.Bind();
    int samplers[2] = {0, 1};
    shader.SetIntArray("u_textures", samplers, 2);

    uint32_t quad_va, quad_vb, quad_ib;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad_va);
    glBindVertexArray(quad_va);

    float vertices[] = {
            // first texture - logo.png
            -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

            // second texture - chessboard.png
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 5));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    uint32_t indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
            4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_ib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_ib);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    uint32_t logo_id = LoadTexture("assets/textures/logo.png");
    uint32_t chessboard_id = LoadTexture("assets/textures/chessboard.png");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.Bind();
        Bind2DTexture(0, logo_id);
        Bind2DTexture(1, chessboard_id);

        glBindVertexArray(quad_va);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

and shader:

```
#type vertex
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texcoord;
layout(location = 0) in float a_texindex;

out vec2 v_texcoord;
out float v_texindex;

void main()
{
        v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        v_texindex = a_texindex;
        gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
}

#type fragment
#version 450 core

in vec2 v_texcoord;
in float v_texindex;

uniform sampler2D u_textures[2];

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
        int index = int(v_texcoord);
        color = texture(u_textures[index], v_texcoord);
}
```

Where the Shader class, which is not shown simply parses the shader file with both, vertex and fragment part. Now both textures are distinguished via last attrib pointer, one float 0.0f for first texture, 1.0f for second one (and are converted to int to be used as index inside shader). But in the output, only the first one, namely the logo.png (as it is set first via `Bind2DTexture(0, logo_id);` will be drawn, whereas chessboard.png will not. However both textures are set as units via `Bind2DTexture`. So why is chessborad.png not drawn?

PS: for completness, here is the shader class:

*header*:

```
#ifndef TEST_SHADER_HPP
#define TEST_SHADER_HPP

#include <string>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Shader {
public:
    explicit Shader(const std::string& filepath);

    void Bind() const;

    void SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const;

    void SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count);

    void SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const;

    void SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const;

    void SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const;

    void SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const;

private:
    static void CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath);

    uint32_t id_;
};

#endif //TEST_SHADER_HP
```

*source*:

```
#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <glad/glad.h>

void Shader::CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath) {
    int success;
    char infoLog[1024];
    if (type != "PROGRAM") {
        glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    } else {
        glGetProgramiv(shader_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    }
}

Shader::Shader(const std::string& filepath) {
    // 1. divide vertex and fragment part
    enum class ShaderType {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        if (line.find("#type") != std::string::npos) {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            } else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Unknown shader: " << line << '\n';
            }
        } else {
            if (type == ShaderType::NONE) {
                std::cout << "No shader defined" << '\n';
            } else {
                ss[(int) type] << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    std::string vertex_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::VERTEX].str();
    std::string fragment_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::FRAGMENT].str();

    // 2. convert, compile and link sources to shader program
    // 2.1 convert string to c str
    const char *vertex_str = vertex_code.c_str();
    const char *fragment_str = fragment_code.c_str();
    // 2.2.1 vertex shader
    uint32_t vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_id, 1, &vertex_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertex_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(vertex_id, "VERTEX", filepath);
    // 2.2.2 fragment shader
    uint32_t fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_id, 1, &fragment_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragment_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(fragment_id, "FRAGMENT", filepath);
    // 2.3 shader program
    id_ = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(id_, vertex_id);
    glAttachShader(id_, fragment_id);
    glLinkProgram(id_);
    CheckCompileErrors(id_, "PROGRAM", filepath);
    // 2.4 delete the shaders as they're linked into program and no longer necessary
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
}

void Shader::Bind() const {
    glUseProgram(id_);
}

void Shader::SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count) {
    glUniform1iv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), count, values);
}

void Shader::SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const {
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const {
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, vec.w);
}

void Shader::SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const {
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
}

void Shader::SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: Sampler arrays may only be indexed by dynamic uniform expressions. Varyings are not allowed

Comment: @BDL the referenced answer to my question (as marked as duplicate), does not answers to my particular example

Comment: You have three options, all of them mentioned in the linked post: 1) don't depend on varyings when you calculate index, 2) use a array texture instead of an array of textures 3) use a 3d texture. If anything is missing, let me know.